# Adding activity indicator LED to 3.3V serial line using enhancement mosfet

Tags: operational-amplifier, led, mosfet, uart, led-driver

I want to make a PCB with a STM32 MCU on it. I will only have a 3.3V supply rail for this PCB. I will be using UART for some communication (AFAIK it is ACTIVE LOW) and I am planning to have activity LEDs for when the UART is doing something.

I will be using highest possible transfer rate (e.g. above 400k baud). Is there a way to add non-intrusive LED indication on these line? I have something like this in mind, but I can not find a actual part for M2 that allows 3.3V as source and <1V as gate.

Please mind that SCM below shwos 5V, but it is meant to be 3.3V

[image]

Is this a reliable solution at all? if so, can you recommend me an actual part number?
If not a good solution, what would you suggest?

**UPDATE**

While searching, I found 74HCT1G125 which is a line buffer with inverted enable pin. Would something like this be feasible?

[image]

Comment: are you out of pins on the mcu already? a "busy" pin is going to be more customizable (in terms of debounce, intensity, etc) than a discrete stack.

Comment: @dandavis I am not out of pins, but I want to achieve a passive solution. That is no code involved and simply turn on the led even so briefly as the tx line goes low (activates at least for one bit)

Comment: ok, but 1 bit would be invisible, so would basically any activity lasting  under 1/100th a second, which is why I suggest a debounce; human factors, not electrical...

Comment: Probably easier to make this circuit with a PNP BJT.

Comment: @Finbarr but that will be wasting power when the TX is idle at high!

Comment: How much power, exactly?

Comment: @ around 10/20 mA

Comment: mA is a measure of current, not power. The only power you'll be wasting is in the LED resistor, but that will be the same whether it's a MOSFET or a BJT driving it.

Comment: I've seen many modules connecting the LED directly to the line with a 1.5k or 2.2k resistor. no Idea how much intrusive it would be.

Comment: The Arduino Uno use directly connected LEDs as Tirdad suggested. But if you don't want the LED drive to affect the UART lines your second solution would work. Or have a look at the answer in this [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/370131/uart-led-driver-using-mosfet)

Comment: _"I will only have a 3.3V supply rail for this PCB."_ - your schematic shows 5V ???

Comment: @BruceAbbott sorry that is a mistake, should be 3.3V

Comment: I see no reason you cannot directly connect the Tx line directly to the gate of a logic level MOSFET. If you want to guarantee it off, put the pull up to the Tx line, not the gate. putting it in the gate circuit as you show it becomes a voltage divider to the gate lowering the voltage.